# C - Add an array of integers in a binary file

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread, fclose

I have to add an array of int passed as parameter in a binary file as argument of the function. In parameter of the function there is also the size of the array.
If the file is empty we write the array but if the file already contains an array, we concatenate the two arrays.
My concern is that at each execution, I am reported a crash.
Here is my code:

```
void appendIntArray(char* filename, int* array, int N){                                          
                                             
    int* buffer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*200);                                            
    FILE* fp;                                            
                                             
    if(fp == NULL) {                                             
        return(N);                                           
    }                                            
                                             
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");                                          
    fread(N, sizeof(int), 1, fp);                                            
    fread(buffer, sizeof(int), N, fp);                                           
    fclose(fp);                                          
                                             
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");                                          
    fwrite(&N, sizeof(int), 1, fp);                                          
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), 1, fp);                                          
    fwrite(array, sizeof(int), N, fp);                                           
                                             
    fclose(fp);                                          
    return(N, buffer,array);                                             
}
```

`
Could someone please tell me why my program crashes and correct me.

If the file is empty we should have an array. If the file already contains an array, I should have two arrays concatenated.

Comment: You can't return something from a function declared to return `void`. And you can't return multiple values in C, you need to return them as a struct.

Comment: The first argument to `fread()` must be a pointer, so `N` must be `&N`. But if you're reading N from the file, why is it a function parameter?

Comment: You should have gotten a compiler warning from the first `fread` line.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions ! I changed the N by &N in the fread() and i changed the return by ```printf("%d %d %d" ,&N, &buffer, &tab);``` but now, it returns the adresses of the numbers whereas i've printed &N, &buffer and &tab. What can i do more ?

Comment: In general, always check for errors. fread(...), write(...) and fclose(...) each can fail, you should check the return value, and report any error, and at least abort.

Comment: Pointers should printed using `%p` format, not `%d`. I'm not sure why you're printing pointers, though. And what is `tab`?

Comment: In general, enable compiler warnings, and check the warning messages printed by the compiler. If there is at least a single warning message (and you are a beginner), then your code is most likely incorrect, so don't be surprised if it crashes. The compiler also prints a line number next to the warning message, so you have an idea which part to fix. My compiler (GCC 7.5) with the default settings (warnings not explicitly enabled), already displays 3 warnings for your code.

Comment: if you check `fp` against `NULL`, do it after calling the `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

Before allocating the buffer, read the current length from the file. Add `N` to that to get the size of the final resulting array, and use that in `malloc()`. Then you can use `memcpy()` to copy the new array to the end of the buffer after the old file contents.

To return the new `N` to the caller, pass this parameter as a pointer.

You need to call `fopen()` *before* you check if `fp` is null.

To return the new array of file contents, you have to declare the function to return `int *`, not `void`.

```
char *appendIntArray(char* filename, int* array, int *N){
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, 'rb');
    if(!fp) {
        return NULL;
    }

    int currentsize;
    fread(&currentsize, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    int* buffer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(currentsize + *N));
    if (!buffer) {
        return array;
    }

    fread(buffer, sizeof(int), currentsize, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(&buffer[currentsize], array, N * sizeof(int));
    *N += currentsize;
    fwrite(N, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), *N, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return buffer;
}
```